# "gar nicht erst" vs "nicht (ein)mal" to express the idea of "not even"

Tags: word-usage

> Wohl besser, wir lassen uns **gar nicht erst** mit dem ein, was?
>
> {vs}: Wohl besser, wir lassen uns mit dem **nicht (ein)mal** ein, was?

In conversation with my friend, the use of "gar nicht erst" came to mind on the spot in this context, but I realised I couldn't really tell how "gar nicht erst" compares with  "nicht (ein)mal"  to express the idea of "not even". I wonder if "gar nicht erst" sounds stronger in tone?

Answer (score 1):

It's not just a difference in tone, but also in meaning.

> Wohl besser, wir lassen uns **gar nicht erst** mit dem ein, was?

"It's better to avoid that guy **from the beginning**. He's nasty."

> Wohl besser, wir lassen uns **nicht einmal** mit dem ein, was?

"It's better to avoid **even** that guy. Though he's the neatest one we met yet."

Comment: Ah, the wrong place for "nicht einmal", qualifying the wrong part! Please take my edit into account.

Comment: @Alone-zee It was better in your 1st version.